# Setting up the IIS website for the intranet only

Tags: networking, iis, windows-server

I am using Windows Server 2019 (Version 1809 Build 17763.348) and IIS (Version 10.0.17763.1) on the server side. On the client side I use Windows 10 (Version 1709 Build 16299.431).

I have my own small network made up of a server and a normal computer. I want to set up a website on the server in the IIS, which is only accessible from my small network. So far I have managed to install the website in the IIS and access it from the web server. However, if I try to access this website from the client, I get the error message "Host not found". I already tried to set up the IP of the server for the web address at the client under C:\Windows\System32...\host. Unfortunately this didn't work either. What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried typing in your Server's IP Address in the client's browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it. What was missing was an entry in the IIS. There I had to edit bindings under Sites. There I entered the IP of the server. Subsequently I made the corresponding entry in the hosts file of the client. So with IP of the server and desired address. Now it works very well. Thanks to Cris for the thought-provoking ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1)

```
Give your server a static IP address
```

Step 2)

```
Start your IIS
```

Step 3)

```
In your servers browser type in it's IP or 127.0.0.1 to check IIS is running
```

Step 4)

```
Type your server's IP in the client's browser
```

Step 5)

```
Once you can see the homepage of your server than start playing with DNS
```

Comment: Thanks you Cris.

My server has a static IP. IIS is running, too.

If I enter 127.0.0.1 or the IP of the server in the browser of the server, the browser says: "The web page was not found". If I enter the IP of the server in the browser of the client I get a 404 (HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.). What am I doing wrong?